# Is there anyway to use JS libraries in Riak?

Tags: javascript, riak

Is there anyway to load JS libraries for Riak Mapreduce queries? What built in libraries are available (I don't mean the Basho provided ones, but things like string, math, etc). I would really prefer not to do copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - if you look in the `app.config` file for Riak you'll find:

```
%% js_source_dir should point to a directory containing Javascript
%% source files which will be loaded by Riak when it initializes
%% Javascript VMs.
%{js_source_dir, "/tmp/js_source"},
```

You can also store JS in Riak itself and use it in your MR queries:

http://wiki.basho.com/MapReduce.html#Map

You'd store a java function in Riak as an object in the bucket "myjs" with the key "mymap" then reference it via

```
{"map":{"language":"javascript","bucket":"myjs","key":"mymap"}}
```